# How to use secondary index for spring data correctely

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, couchbase, sql++, spring-data-couchbase

I have a couchbase bucket named `order` which contain almost 2000 document, i created a secondary index (idx_customer) for this bucket in order to optimize my queries :

The query **hit** the index when executed in couchbase Query Monitor.

but i think it **miss** the index when played from spring data repository.
mainly because the sorting and paging in the repository make my query translated in other queries that miss the index.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_customer ON `order` (
buyer.contact.firstName , 
buyer.contact.lastName , 
ALL DISTINCT ARRAY aoc.`communicationValue` FOR aoc IN buyer.contact.communicationChannel
WHEN aoc.`communicationChannelCode`= "EMAIL" END)
WHERE _class = "com.lbk.entities.OrderEntity"
```

I query for order inside my spring boot applicaiton using spring data with this repository:

```
import com.lbk.entities.OrderEntity;
import com.lbk.entities.OrderMetadataEntity;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.query.N1qlPrimaryIndexed;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.query.N1qlSecondaryIndexed;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.query.ViewIndexed;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;

import java.util.List;

@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "orderEntity")
@N1qlSecondaryIndexed(indexName = "idx_customer")
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
public interface OrdersRepository extends CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<OrderEntity, String> {

    List<OrderMetadataEntity> findAllBy();

    Page<OrderMetadataEntity> findAllBy(Pageable page);

    @Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE #{#n1ql.filter} "
                    + "AND orderTypeCode = $1 "
                    + "AND (orderCategory != $2 OR orderCategory is not valued ) "
                    + "AND buyer.contact.firstName is not null"
    )
    Page<OrderMetadataEntity> findOrders(String orderTypeCode, String excludedOrderCategory, Pageable page);

    @Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE #{#n1ql.filter} "
                    + "AND creationDateTime >= STR_TO_MILLIS($1) AND creationDateTime <= STR_TO_MILLIS($2) "
                    + "AND orderTypeCode = $3 "
                    + "AND (orderCategory != $4 OR orderCategory is not valued )"
```

+ "AND buyer.contact.firstName is not null"
        )
        Page findOrdersByCreationDateTimeBetween(
                        String start,
                        String end,
                        String orderTypeCode,
                        String excludedOrderCategory,
                        Pageable page
        );

```
}
```

**But the performance and the logging shows that for sur i am not using the index**
what s wrong? and how to query properly secondary index form my repository?

for this paged N1QL query :

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE #{#n1ql.filter} "
                                + "AND orderTypeCode = $1 "
                                + "AND (orderCategory != $2 OR orderCategory is not valued ) "
                                + "AND buyer.contact.firstName is not null")
Page<OrderMetadataEntity> findOrders(String orderTypeCode, String excludedOrderCategory, Pageable page);
```

I have the flowing three queries in the logs :

1. Query for counting the documents.
2. Query to fetch the first page of documents.
3. Query to fetch sub documents (SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(orderLineItem)) (I wonder why !!!).

Here is the spring data logs:

```
Executing N1QL query: {\"args\":[\"%mohammed%\",\"%mohammed%\",null,\"220\",\"EXECLUDED_CATEGORY\"],\"statement\":\"SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM `order` WHERE `_class` = \\"com.lbk.entities.OrderEntity\\" AND ( LOWER(buyer.contact.firstName) LIKE $1 OR LOWER(buyer.contact.lastName) LIKE $2 OR ANY communicationChannel IN buyer.contact.communicationChannel SATISFIES ( communicationChannel.communicationChannelCode = 'EMAIL' AND communicationChannel.communicationValue  = $3 ) END )  AND orderTypeCode = $4 AND (orderCategory != $5 OR O2.orderCategory is not valued )AND creationDateTime in (select RAW max(O2.creationDateTime) from `order` O2 WHERE ( LOWER(O2.buyer.contact.firstName) LIKE $1 OR LOWER(O2.buyer.contact.lastName) LIKE $2 OR ANY communicationChannel IN O2.buyer.contact.communicationChannel SATISFIES ( communicationChannel.communicationChannelCode = 'EMAIL' AND communicationChannel.communicationValue  = $3 ) END )  AND ANY communicationChannel IN O2.buyer.contact.communicationChannel SATISFIES ( communicationChannel.communicationChannelCode = 'EMAIL' AND communicationChannel.communicationValue is not null ) END AND O2.orderTypeCode = $4 AND (O2.orderCategory != $5 OR O2.orderCategory is not valued) group by ( ARRAY item.communicationValue FOR item IN O2.buyer.contact.communicationChannel WHEN item.communicationChannelCode = 'EMAIL' END ) )AND buyer.contact.firstName IS NOT NULL\",\"scan_consistency\":\"statement_plus\"}
Executing N1QL query: {\"args\":[\"%mohammed%\",\"%mohammed%\",null,\"220\",\"EXECLUDED_CATEGORY\"],\"statement\":\"SELECT META(`order`).id AS _ID, META(`order`).cas AS _CAS, `order`.* FROM `order` WHERE `_class` = \\"com.lbk.entities.OrderEntity\\" AND ( LOWER(buyer.contact.firstName) LIKE $1 OR LOWER(buyer.contact.lastName) LIKE $2 OR ANY communicationChannel IN buyer.contact.communicationChannel SATISFIES ( communicationChannel.communicationChannelCode = 'EMAIL' AND communicationChannel.communicationValue  = $3 ) END )  AND orderTypeCode = $4 AND (orderCategory != $5 OR O2.orderCategory is not valued )AND creationDateTime in (select RAW max(O2.creationDateTime) from `order` O2 WHERE ( LOWER(O2.buyer.contact.firstName) LIKE $1 OR LOWER(O2.buyer.contact.lastName) LIKE $2 OR ANY communicationChannel IN O2.buyer.contact.communicationChannel SATISFIES ( communicationChannel.communicationChannelCode = 'EMAIL' AND communicationChannel.communicationValue  = $3 ) END )  AND ANY communicationChannel IN O2.buyer.contact.communicationChannel SATISFIES ( communicationChannel.communicationChannelCode = 'EMAIL' AND communicationChannel.communicationValue is not null ) END AND O2.orderTypeCode = $4 AND (O2.orderCategory != $5 OR O2.orderCategory is not valued) group by ( ARRAY item.communicationValue FOR item IN O2.buyer.contact.communicationChannel WHEN item.communicationChannelCode = 'EMAIL' END ) )AND buyer.contact.firstName IS NOT NULL ORDER BY `creationDateTime` DESC LIMIT 18 OFFSET 0\",\"scan_consistency\":\"statement_plus\"}
Executing N1QL query: {\"args\":[\"069cf983-8ed7-4b8f-845d-175593d4ca49\"],\"statement\":\"SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(orderLineItem) FROM `order` WHERE `_class` = \\"com.lbk.entities.OrderEntity\\" AND META().id = $1\",\"scan_consistency\":\"statement_plus\"}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Queries will not be able to use idx_customer index because it doesn't qualify. Please
Checkout "Designing Index For Query In Couchbase N1QL" in https://blog.couchbase.com/n1ql-practical-guide-second-edition

The index is partial index and has only entries for the document that has _class = "com.lbk.entities.OrderEntity" but none of your queries will not have this predicate so it can't use that index. In addition query predicate (each OR part of predicate) must hvae leading index key as query predicate to use the index. That is not the case for queries in the log.  You can try non partial index if you want.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_customer1 ON `order` (_class, 
buyer.contact.firstName , 
buyer.contact.lastName , 
ALL DISTINCT ARRAY aoc.`communicationValue` FOR aoc IN buyer.contact.communicationChannel
WHEN aoc.`communicationChannelCode`= "EMAIL" END);
```

Comment: all my queries qualify for the index when explained in query monitor,  _class = "com.lbk.entities.OrderEntity"  is added by spring data for my first 2 logs.
the leading index key is added to all the queries

Comment: using your suggested index, i got the same perfs.

thanks for your help

Comment: Using this query with your index :

SELECT META(`order`).id AS _ID, META(`order`).cas AS _CAS, `order`.* FROM `order` 
WHERE `_class` = "com.lbk.entities.OrderEntity" AND orderTypeCode = '220' 
AND (orderCategory != 'EXCLUDED' OR orderCategory is not valued ) 
AND buyer.contact.firstName is not null ORDER BY `creationDateTime` DESC


it take elapsed: 6.20s | execution: 6.20s | count: 2345 | size: 80916114

Comment: CREATE INDEX idx_customer2 ON `order` (orderTypeCode,creationDateTime DESC)
WHERE _class = "com.lbk.entities.OrderEntity"

Comment: Thanks you very much Vsr, i finally think that even if my queries hit the index, it's maybe a bad idea to use spring-data